# How do I apply displacement texture on selected faces of a mesh?

Tags: mesh, texturing, displacement

I follow this 3D artist on IG, and I am wondering how he applied the lug textures to the mesh (imported from Gravity Sketch) at only the selected faces. And how would I model the texture lugs to then fade on the sides. See attached for image

[image]

Comment: Hello, you could use a b&w image as texture brush in Sculpt mode

Answer (score 2):

You could use a black and white image as stencil brush in *Sculpt* mode:

[image]

Here is the image I've used:

[image]

Keep the *Draw* brush, open the N panel, under *Brush Settings > Texture*, select the brush, and *Mapping > Stencil*, then sculpt. Of course your topology needs to be high enough:

[image]

Instead you could simply fake the 3D relief with a bump map, but the 3D effect is limited.