# How to add embossed complex logo on a curved surface like a bottle?

Tags: modeling

I’m really having a hard time trying to emboss or deboss a logo / typography on a shape other than a flat plane. For example trying to get a logo on a curved bottle. I would like to have the edge loop around the logo smooth out and blend into the curved surface as well. I would like to seek for a solution that not using displacement map but actual creating an actual 3D mesh for the object with the embossed logo. Much appreciate any help or solution! [image]

Comment: I would use a bump map or a normal map, maybe even both.

Comment: For an actual 3d mesh, probably this kind of technics: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/290356/19156

Comment: Why not using a bump map? If you want a real displacement you could use a Dsiplace modifier

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface